# Server with multiple clients using fork()

Tags: c, sockets, client-server, fork

This is my scenario: my server should handle two clients at the same time using sockets and `fork()`. Server shares with both clients the **same** int array `data[]` , obtained randomly. If `data[2]` is a precise number, client1 does its stuff and resend its work to server, else client2 does its stuff ecc.. This continues in an infinite loop, till a server side CTRL+C signal.
I think my problem is in this server snippet I wrote so far:

```
//...
while (1) {
  printf("\n*****server waiting for new client connection:*****\n");

  msgsock=accept(sock,(struct sockaddr *)&client,(socklen_t *)&lenght);
  if(msgsock == -1){
    perror("accept");
    exit(-1);}
  pid = fork();
  if (pid == 0){
    do{
      srand((unsigned) time(&t));
      data[0] = rand() %15;
      data[1] = rand() %10;
      data[2] = rand() %2;
      printf("I wrote %d %d %d\n", data[0], data[1], data[2]);
      if(write(msgsock,data,sizeof(data))<0){
        perror("writing message");}
      if(read(msgsock,data2,sizeof(data))<0){ //read the result from client
        perror("reading message");}
      printf("Result is %d\n", data2[3]);} 
      while(1);
    exit(0);}
```

This works for one client at a time, as soon as I run the second client, it creates a new child and only handles the newer client. I want that both clients are served, depending on the content of `data[2]` at every loop.
Thanks in advance.

**EDIT:**
I can't use shared memory or similars and threads, only sockets and semaphores. The use of `fork` is only an idea I had trying to solve the exercise.

Comment: `read(msgsock,data2,sizeof(data))` looks suspicious, don't you mean `sizeof(data2)`?

Comment: What is the point of `if (pid == 0)` if you want this to run on both forks?

Comment: As for your problem, you might want to use threads instead? Or shared memory?

Comment: I think you should not use `exit(0)` but `_exit(0)` instead.

Comment: If you want to share stuff consider not using the fork model. It is obsolete by today's standards.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg yes, it's `sizeof(data2)`. It is an exercise, I cannot use shared memory and I dont' know nothing about threads, maybe I can use semaphores, if there is no way to solve it using only `fork()`

Comment: Do you *have* to use `fork`? Or could you do it in a single process and use e.g. `select` to multiplex the sockets? The problem is that you can't share data between processes, not without using e.g. shared memory or similar.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg I must not use shared memory or messages queue, I can only use sockets and signals (and semaphores, if they can be useful).

Comment: If can have only two connected clients, and it's only the single `data[2]` entry that is significant, you can use signals (e.g. the `SIGUSR1` and/or the `SIGUSR2`) to communicate the status of `data[2]` between the processes. However, you probably have to use the parent process to act as an intermediate between the child processes, as they will not know about each other (well, the second child process knows the pid of the first child process, but not the opposite).

Comment: You can also use a socket to communicate between the child processes.

Comment: You mean something like "if `data[2]==1` send `SIGUSR1`, If `data[2]==2` send `SIGUSR2`"? And how can I use the parent as an intermediate? Not sure if I am able to do so, do you know some similar examples, around the web?

Answer (score 0):

On forking, you create a second process that is a clone of the original one. This means that all data structures in your process will be duplicated. If you modify them in one process afterwards, these changes will not be seen in the other process. So sharing information between the two forked off client handlers will not work by simply writing values to an array. You might use shared memory for this, but using threads or switching to nonblocking I/O might be a better choice in your case. If your exercise requires using `fork`, you could use sockets or pipes to help the forked processes communicate, but that seems rather complicated.

You also should know that by default, on `fork()`, you duplicate all file descriptors. That means on the first fork, both of the socket descriptors are cloned. Your child process, which you want to use for handling the client, will have a handle to the listening socket which it doesn't need. The parent likewise will have an open descriptor for the client connection. Close `sock` in your child and `msgsock` in your parent (else part, when pid != 0). Also, you should clean up finished child processes in the parent by calling e.g. `wait()` on `SIGCHLD`, otherwise you'd pile up zombie processes every time a client disconnects.

Finally, it is advisable to handle return values < 0 for `accept()/read()/write()` properly by checking `errno`. You might just be getting `EAGAIN` or `EINTR` which basically means "retry the same call", but instead you bail out (accept), or simply advance to the next statement (read/write). If your protocol requires the alternation of read, write, read, write, one of them might fail due to a signal and you skip over it. So it is possible you're doing another read without a write in between, but the connected client really expects some data, waiting forever, never sending anything back.

Comment: The exercise does not require using `fork`, it requires only the use of sockets (and semaphores) and **not** shared memory or message queues. My problem is that I don't know  how to handle 2 or more clients at the same time, sharing between them the **same** array. Using `fork` is only an idea I had.